# Beam ReadFromKafka `with_metadata=True` encoding error

Tags: python, apache-kafka, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Using ReadFromKafka from Python SDK 2.49.0 (calling Java harness) raises encoding error when using `with_metadata=True`:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to encode element 'org.apache.beam.sdk.io.kafka.KafkaIO$ByteArrayKafkaRecord@6e23419d' with coder 'SchemaCoder<Schema: Fields:
Field{name=topic, description=, type=STRING NOT NULL, options={{}}}
Field{name=partition, description=, type=INT32 NOT NULL, options={{}}}
Field{name=offset, description=, type=INT64 NOT NULL, options={{}}}
Field{name=timestamp, description=, type=INT64 NOT NULL, options={{}}}
Field{name=key, description=, type=BYTES, options={{}}}
Field{name=value, description=, type=BYTES, options={{}}}
Field{name=headers, description=, type=ARRAY<ROW<key STRING NOT NULL, value BYTES NOT NULL> NOT NULL>, options={{}}}
Field{name=timestampTypeId, description=, type=INT32 NOT NULL, options={{}}}
Field{name=timestampTypeName, description=, type=STRING NOT NULL, options={{}}}
Encoding positions:
{headers=6, timestampTypeName=8, partition=1, offset=2, topic=0, value=5, key=4, timestamp=3, timestampTypeId=7}
```

Pipeline correctly works using `with_metadata=False` for both Azure Event Hub and Confluent's Cluster.

I'm using default encoders as documentation states: https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/current/apache_beam.io.kafka.html#apache_beam.io.kafka.ReadFromKafka

Pipeline fragment:

```
with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
    reviews = (
        p
        | ReadFromKafka(
            consumer_config={
                "bootstrap.servers": stream_bootstrap_servers,
                "group.id": stream_group_id,
                "security.protocol": "SASL_SSL",
                "sasl.mechanism": "PLAIN",
                "sasl.jaas.config": stream_sasl_jaas_config,
            },
            max_num_records=stream_max_num_records,
            start_read_time=stream_start_read_time,
            topics=[stream_topic],
            with_metadata=True,
        )
    )

    reviews | "Logging messages" >> beam.Map(logging.info)
```

Comment: This sounds like a bug. Will you be able to file an Beam Github issue with instructions to reproduce ? https://beam.apache.org/community/contact-us/